# Postgres "CREATE TABLE AS (SELECT ...)" stuck

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2, pgmodeler

I am using Python with `psycopg2` 2.8.6 against Postgresql 11.6 (also tried on 11.9)

When I am running a query

```
CREATE TABLE tbl AS (SELECT (row_number() over())::integer "id", "col" FROM tbl2)
```

Code is getting stuck (`cursor.execute` never returns), killing the transaction with `pg_terminate_backend` removes the query from the server, but the code is not released. Yet in this case, the target table is created.

Nothing locks the transaction. The internal `SELECT` query on its own was tested and it works well.

I tried analysing clues on the server and found out the following inside `pg_stat_activity`:

- Transaction `state` is `idle in transaction`
- `wait_event_type` is `Client`
- `wait_event` is `ClientRead`

**The same effect** is happening when I am running the query from within *SQL editor (pgModeler)*, but in this case, the query is **stuck** on `Idle` state and the target table is created.

I am not sure what is wrong and how to proceed from here.
Thanks!

Comment: Looks similar problem here , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11306583/postgres-client-locking-up-when-creating-new-table

Comment: Then your "standard SQL editor" has the same problem. Believe me or not: if the session is **idle in transaction** and **waiting to read from the client**, that's exactly what it is doing. It is the client that is confused and sits on its thumbs rather than proceed.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, it happens on this specific kind of query (the query itself is long and contains references to ~500 columns) with different DB instances and table (also long queries) and 2 different kinds of SQL editors. Also reproduced on v11.7. It's only happening with CREATE TABLE AS SELECT or SELECT INTO queries and nothing special is reported in logs.

Is there any way to trace what exactly happens to the connection and why Postgres thinks the connection is and waiting and client gets stuck? Tnx

Comment: You'd have to trace or debug the client code. Perhaps there is a timeout that causes misbehavior if the query takes too long, but I am only guessing. If psycopg2 is used in both cases, maybe the problem is there. I can guarantee that this has nothing to do with the database server.

Comment: What does `SELECT (row_number() over())::integer "id", "col" FROM tbl2` returns ? ;-) Also, are you expecting a duplicate of the table or a calculated table updating over time ( VIEW) ?

Comment: I don't see how this question is related to a programming problem. The problem persists for SQL editors also, so maybe is better to move your question on another Stack site?

Answer (score 2):

I am answering my own question here, to make it helpful for others.

The problem was solved by modifying `tcp_keepalives_idle` Postgres setting from default 2 hours to 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not reporducible, you have to investigate more. You must share more details about your database table, your python code and server OS.

You can also share with us the `strace` attached to Python, so we can see what actually happens during the query.

---

- **wait_event_type = Client**: The server process is waiting for some activity on a socket from user applications, and that the server expects something to happen that is independent from its internal processes. `wait_event` will identify the specific wait point.
- **wait_event = ClientRead**: A session that waits for `ClientRead` is done processing the last query and waits for the client to send the next request. The only way that such a session can block anything is if its state is `idle in transaction`. All locks are held until the transaction ends, and no locks are held once the transaction finishes.
- **Idle in transaction:** The activity can be `idle` (i.e., waiting for a client command), `idle in transaction` (waiting for client inside a `BEGIN` block), or a command type name such as `SELECT`. Also, waiting is appended if the server process is presently waiting on a lock held by another session.

The problem could be related to:

- Network problems
- Uncommitted transaction someplace that has created the same table name.
- The transaction is not committed

You pointed out that is not a commit problem because the SQL editor do the same, but in your question you specify that the editor succesfully create the table.

In pgModeler you see `idle`, that means the *session* is idle, not the query.

If the session is idle, the "query" column of `pg_stat_activity` shows the last executed statement in that session.
So this simply means all those sessions properly ended their transaction using a ROLLBACK statement.

If sessions remain in state `idle in transaction` for a longer time, that is always an application bug where the application is not ending the transaction.

You can do two things:

- Set the [`idle_in_transaction_session_timeout`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/runtime-config-client.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-CLIENT-STATEMENT) so that these transactions are automatically rolled back by the server after a while. This will keep locks from being held indefinitly, but your application will receive an error.
- Fix the application as shown below

---

## `.commit()` solution

The only way that I found to reproduce the problem is to omit the `commit` action.

The module `psycopg2` is [Python DB API](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/)-compliant, so the auto-commit feature is off by default.

Whit this option set to `False` you need to call [`conn.commit`](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/connection.html#connection.commit) to commit any pending transaction to the database.

### Enable auto-commit

You can enable the [auto-commit](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/connection.html#connection.autocommit) as follow:

```
import psycopg2

connection = None

try:
    connection = psycopg2.connect("dbname='myDB' user='myUser' host='localhost' password='myPassword'")
    connection.autocommit = True
except:
    print "Connection failed."

if(connection != None):
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    try:
        cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE tbl AS (SELECT (row_number() over())::integer 'id', 'col' FROM tbl2)""")
    except:
        print("Failed to create table.")
```

### `with` statement

You can also use the [`with`](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/connection.html#connection.autocommit) statement to auto-commit a transaction:

```
with connection, connection.cursor() as cursor:  # start a transaction and create a cursor
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE tbl AS (SELECT (row_number() over())::integer 'id', 'col' FROM tbl2)""")
```

### Traditional way

If you don't want to auto-commit the transaction you need to do it manually calling `.commit()` after your `execute`.

Comment: I don't see how this answer is related to the question asked. The problem persists for SQL editors also - with or without transactions. (see comments)

Answer (score -1):

just remove the `( )` around the `SELECT...`

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-createtableas.html